# Template Metaprogramming To Check the Meaning of an Identifier

Tags: c++, visual-c++, template-meta-programming

**Problem**:
I am using VC++2010, so except a few supported features like `decltype` pre-C++11 is required.

Given a C++ identifier, is it possible to use some meta-programming techniques to check if that identifier is a type name or variable name. In order words, given the code below :

```
void f() {
  s=(uint32)-1;
}
```

is it possible to somehow identify if `uint32` is:

1. the name of a variable which means the RHS of the assignment is a subtraction;or
2. a type name where the RHS operand is literal -1 typecasted to (`uint32`)

by something like `mytemplate<uint32>` or similiar?

**Rationale**: I am using my own in-house developed mini parser to analyze/instrument C++ source code. But my mini parser lacks many features like building a table of identifier types so it always interpret the above code as either subtraction or typecast. My parser is able to modify the source code so that I can insert/modify anything surrounding the `uint32` e.g.

```
void f() {
  s=(mytemplate<uint32>(...))-1;
  s=myfunc(uint32)-1;
}
```

But my inserted code will cause syntax error depending on the meaning of the identifier `uint32` (type name Vs variable name). I am looking for some generic code that I can insert to cater for both cases.

Comment: You've just stumbled unto the reason why `typename` & `template` keyword are sometimes required when defining the bodies of function & class templates.

Comment: Don't write your own parser.  Use the obsolete GCCXML or Clang.

Comment: C++ grammar is not [context-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar). It is impossible to parse without maintaining a symbol table and performing name lookup for every name.